# Insetar datos con ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, pdo, post

> Quiero insertar los datos pero no se si estoy mal en alguna parte me manda a mi alerta de No registrado

```
      <form id="pagos" method="POST">
               <p> $ </p> <input class="inputcolor" name="" id="venta">
               <button type="button" id="guardar" class="btn btn-color">Guardar</button
      </form>

      <script type="text/javascript">
         $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#guardar').click(function() {
            venta = $('#venta').val();
            ins_datos(venta);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Ya lo probé sin querer insertar los datos sin usar Ajax y si funciona

---

```
    $venta = $_POST['venta'];

    $fecha = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $ins = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO ventas VALUES (DEFAULT, :fecha , :dinero)");
    $ins->bindParam(':fecha', $fecha);
    $ins->bindParam(':dinero', $venta);
```

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código de la petición AJAX.

Comment: ¿Qué código Ajax estás usando?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quita el form y llama con un evento onclick a una función que tenga el siguiente código.

```html
    <p> $ </p> <input class="inputcolor" name="" id="venta">
       <button type="button" id="guardar" class="btn btn-color" onclick="enviar()">Guardar</button>
```

```js
        function enviar(){
        var datosInput=$("#venta").val();
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: url,// url script php
          data: {datos:datosInput},//
          succes: function(d){
          console.log(d);//si retornas un json desde php recuerda poner la cabecera application/json
          }
         }
        });
```